# Restrict account creation on lead creation

Tags: apex

I want to restrict users to convert lead if the account name does not match the lead company name.

Please help

Comment: Can you explain what you have already tried doing to achieve this?

Comment: Hi Amit. Your question appears to be asking for other people to write code for you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you

Comment: Himanshu:Not asking to write code .  Not able to find how to do so asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through a validation rule on the Lead object.

For the condition formula would be something like

```
AND(Account__r.Name != Company,
    isConverted=True)
```

Then You could display the  error message as:

```
"Lead cannot be converted!  Reason: Account Name not equal with the Lead Company name!"
```

[image]

Comment: Used the formula but giving error  Error: Field Account__r does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: it might have a different API name on your org, as you can see there is a insert  field button, if you click on it and go to the 'Account>' list name , then select the Name field value from it, should fix your issue

Comment: When i click on insert Field not able to find account. It would really be helpful you can post a screenshot.

Comment: well you might not have a look up relationship to Account from Leads in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you'll need a trigger to accomplish this task. Generally speaking, it'd look like this:

```
trigger validateLeadCompany on Lead (after update) {
  Lead[] conversions = new Lead[0];
  for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) {
    if(Trigger.old[index].IsConverted != Trigger.new[index].IsConverted) {
      conversions.add(Trigger.new[index]);
    }
  }
  if(!conversions.isEmpty()) {
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
      [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN 
      (SELECT ConvertedAccountId FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :conversions)]);
    for(Lead record: conversions) {
      if(accounts.containsKey(record.ConvertedAccountId) && 
         record.Company != accounts.get(record.ConvertedAccountId).Name) {
        record.addError('Company name must match converted account name.');
      }
  }
```